# Stitching 2D matrix of orthographic images (planar) for microscopy, C#

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I have built a microscope scanning system where I can achieve multiple overlapping flat image tile mosaics in 2D (and 3D).

I want to stitch the images together, I have tried/examined various approaches with Emgu and Accord, but I am not an expert, and it seems that grid stitching is not there.
All I need to do is to orthographic 'stitch' a grid of 2D images together. I can reduce or alter bitmap resolution via scaling no problem. It doesn't have to be exact subpixel.

I've found several solutions for 'panoramic' stitching, but not yet any solutions for 2D "orthomosaic" grid stitching.
Basically, I want to do something similar (but fast) to the extinct microsoft image compositor or ImageJ for simple planar 2D image grid.

This must be simple! I'm a bit of a beginner but reasonably good at C#, and very much thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching in affine Mode, but its python

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with OpenCV but using Bioformats one can use the SaveBytes method to write a portion of an image into a Bioformats supported file format. https://bio-formats.readthedocs.io/en/v6.13.0/developers/tiling.html